# '#12768949' is not a valid hex color google geochart

Tags: google-visualization

Whenever I try to add google geochart to my website the chart looks like this:
[image: '#12768949' is not a valid hex color].

And I get an error that says #12768949' is not a valid hex color. If I try it on an empty
react project it works like on [the official site](https://react-google-charts.com/geo-chart).

Does someone know what the issue might be?

What I tried so far: removed bootstrap, removed my app.css file

The only time it works is when no other components are rendered...

Comment: That's not the official site for Google Geo Charts; that's a site for a React layer around Google Geo Charts. The official Google Geo Charts page has a google.com address: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart. As far as the error goes, standard hex colors are 6 digits long (`#000000` for black, e.g.). Eight digit hex codes allow for an alpha channel, but [it is less widely supported](https://caniuse.com/css-rrggbbaa) than [the six-digit format](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_types_color_rgb_hexadecimal_notation)

Comment: Thank you I think I will try with the official site then. I get that error from the google server I guess. I don't see the error on my client or on the server so it has to be from google.